# CanActivate Issue TS2720

Tags: angular

i have an issue on CanActivate

```
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router/src/utils/preactivation';

import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, Router } from '@angular/router';

import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {

    constructor(private authService: AuthService,
                private router: Router)
    {

    }
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot )
    : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> |boolean {

        if (this.authService.isAuth) {
            return true;
        }else{
            this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
        }
    }
}
```

and it's telling me this :

> ERROR in src/app/services/auth-guard.service.ts(10,14): error TS2720:
>   Class 'AuthGuard' incorrectly implements class 'CanActivate'. Did you
>   mean to extend 'Can Activate' and inherit its members as a subclass?
>   Type 'AuthGuard' is missing the following properties from type
>   'CanActivate': path, route

But I don't understand why ?

Great thanks to everyone !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You've imported the `CanActivate` interface from the wrong place. It should be

`import { CanActivate } from '@angular/router';`

And it's also a good idea to `return false` in the `else` statement.

Comment: Thank you a lot ^^

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help :) Can you mark the question as answered by clicking on the checkmark on the left :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have `strict` enabled. Your function specifies return type: `Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> | boolean`, but you are not returning anything from the else branch. Meaning, that your return type is `true | undefined` or `boolean | undefined`. You have to return something from the else branch:

```
import { Observable, EMPTY } from 'rxjs'
// and so on
    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,state: RouterStateSnapshot )
    : Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> |boolean {

        if (this.authService.isAuth) {
            return true;
        }else{
            this.router.navigate(['/auth']);
            return EMPTY;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but it was just CanActivate which was in wrong Import folder. :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was a careless mistake where I was providing

```
        canActivate: AuthGuard,
```

instead of

```
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
```

Notice the square brackets